# RKE2 in HA cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rke2

Im trying to learn RKE2 which in some cases is different from classic k8s, and I have an issue with setting up HA cluster. I want to have 3 master nodes / 3 worker nodes and physical LB. Lets say:

Master nodes IP: 10.0.0.10 10.0.0.11 10.0.0.12

Worker nodes IP: 10.0.0.50 10.0.0.51 10.0.0.52

LB: 10.0.0.100

How do I setup HA?

I've tried to install rke2 with config.yaml file with line:

tls-san:

```
10.0.0.10
10.0.0.11
10.0.0.12
```

on first master node, and on second and third:

server: 10.0.0.100:9345

tls-san:

```
10.0.0.10
10.0.0.11
10.0.0.12
```

And also i added config to LB where is listening for port 9345 and 6443, and its not working